# rails 3.2.2 Unable to deserialize serialized model object - strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, deserialization

I apologize for the long/complicated question.

Using rails 3.2.2 (ruby 1.9.3-p194), we are saving user-specific ActiveRecord model objects to the session using Dalli/memcached for the session store, and during development we sometimes see an error when retrieving data from the session:

```
ArgumentError (Unable to unmarshal value: dump format error for symbol(0x46)):
```

Usually, the error happens when there's something wrong with the data (e.g., the object has a foreign key pointing to a non-existent record).

However, we still get this error whenever we add or remove a record involving a many-to-many association, even though all foreign keys are valid and everything seems to be correct (after blowing away databases, killing rails and memcache servers, etc.).

The many-to-many association is implemented with a join table and has_many-through.  A highly simplified view of our schema is:

```
  User
   |
 Profile
  |  \
  .   \
  .    \
  .     \
  |      \
 Foo ==== Bar
```

where a User has many Profiles, a Profile has many Foos (indirectly, through other tables), a Profile has many Bars, and Foos and Bars have many of each other through the BarFoo join table.

The error is normally triggered when adding/removing a Foo to/from a Bar.  Although we became aware of it at the point of retrieving from the session, the session/memcache itself is not to blame, since the error can be forced to happen even before the data is stored in the session.

To eliminate the session from the equation, I've inserted this code right after the Foo/Bar record creation/deletion:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(user)) # throws exception first time
```

This throws an exception.  The really puzzling thing is this:  If I catch the exception so that the request can continue to be processed, the user object is actually stored in the session and will be fetched after that *with no problems*.  (I found this out because during a debugging breakpoint, running the above code once fails, and immediately running it again succeeds and "fixes" the problem when execution continues.)

Even stranger, if instead of the above code, immediately after Foo/Bar creation/deletion I do:

```
Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(profile)) # does not throw any exception
```

I get no exception at all, and the rest of the code works (the user is stored and retrieved from the session with no errors).

I've read a lot of discussions that seem to say that AR model instances should not be cached, because they may contain procs, IO, etc.  However, we are not getting TypeErrors when dumping the objects.  The fact that the problem is "corrected" by running the serialization/deserialization twice on the User model or once on its child model is very puzzling.  How can the serialized representation of an object be invalid one moment and valid the next?

Can anyone tell me if this is a bug in rails?  Or are we doing something that is not supported?  Is there a way to serialize model objects with their associated models, or do I have to implement my own serialization/deserialization code for model objects and their associations?

Update: this error is not limited to the many-to-many association.  It also happens when creating/updating/deleting other tables in the schema, but in those cases it is much more rare and virtually impossible to reproduce.